# Get criteria not match the schema

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Im trying to get an Item from DynamoDB based on Primary Key but it throws me an exception:

*ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema*

Here is how my table looks:
[image]

I'm following a tutorial and here is how I wrote my get:

```
let params = {
    TableName: process.env.CALL_NAVEGATION_HISTORY_TABLE,
    Key: {
        "Id": requestBody.CallSid
    }
}

dynamoDb.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log('Error on dynamodb', err);
        callback(null, Helpers.xmlTwimlResponse(twiml));
    }
    console.log(data);
    callback(null, Helpers.xmlTwimlResponse(twiml));

});
```

What is wrong on my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the most obvious thing is what we miss right in front of our eyes.

```
let params = {
    TableName: process.env.CALL_NAVEGATION_HISTORY_TABLE,
    Key: {
        "Id": requestBody.CallSid
    }
}
```

The Key name is case-sensitive. If you change it to 'id' it should work fine.